# Муж или супруг?

Tags: этимология

В вопросе "Лишнее слово" "супруга" назвали старославянизмом. То есть, получается, что слова "супруг", "супруга" и "супружество" более старые, чем "муж", "жена" и "свадьба"? И интересно бы узнать происхождение этого слова.
Спасибо.

Comment: Уважаемая Fuchoin Kazuki, я не против Вашего решения, просто из любопытства, объясните, пожалуйста, Ваш выбор. Я что-то не так написала? Очень уважаю Виктора, и баллы мне как-то не нужны (это просто форум, не какой-то конкурс), но ведь у него добавочка к моему ответу, а самого ответа о происхождении нет. Почему выбран его ответ? Я что-то не очень понимаю законы этого сайта. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Употребление слов "супруг, муж" и "супруга, жена" можно рассматривать еще и с точки зрения речевого этикета. О собственной "второй половинке" принято говорить "муж, жена", а о чужой - "супруг, супруга". Поэтому нарушением речевого этикета будет фраза: "Мой супруг просил передать привет Вашей жене". Правильно будет так: "Мой муж просил передать привет Вашей супруге" и соответственно: "Моя жена просила передать привет Вашей супруге"

Answer (score 6):

Почему более старые? Функционировали в одно время - в древнерусском языке как синонимы, оттенки значения были чуть разные: муж - человек мужского пола - общеславянское. Но вот муж становится главой семьи - тогда он супруг.По Фасмеру происходит от др.-русск. супругъ «парная упряжка; супруг, супружеская пара, муж и жена», наряду с съпругъ «супруг», ст.-слав. сѫпрѫгъ (ζεῦγος; Остром.) Слово супруг заимствовано из старославянского. Производное от съпрушти (1 л. ед. ч. - съпрягу), т.е. "стянуть, соединить, запрячь". Буквально супруги означает  "сопряженные, в одной упряжи". Сейчас имеет  помету" официальное (офиц.)".  Не только официальное, но и несколько устарелое, иногда - "ироничное": "Я бы поехал, да вот только супруга моя не пускает!". Старославянский - письменный язык, не разговорный, поэтому слово и закрепилось в официальном стиле - у нотариусов например.

Так что теперь в этом значении муж и супруг различаются стилистически. Муж-нейтральное, супруг - устаревшее, официальное, ироническое.

Кстати, у народных этимологов есть "интересное" объяснение происхождение слов муж и жена: [Происхождение слов МУЖ и ЖЕНА | proza.ru](http://www.proza.ru/2011/08/14/745) Ненаучно, но оригинально.

Comment: >Кстати, у народных этимологов   
  
И чего оригинального-то? :)
 Как раз слово супруг восходит к "сопрястися", что означало "состоять в половой связи". Упряжка - да, но какая.

Comment: Это не народные,это наука, а народные - по ссылке:
..ЖМУЖМУЖМУЖМУЖМУЖМУ..., ...НАЖЕНАЖЕНАЖЕНАЖЕ...  и через некоторое время сообразим, что произносим искомые понятия: ....Ж-МУЖ-МУЖ-МУЖ-МУЖ... и ...НА-ЖЕНА-ЖЕНА-ЖЕНА-ЖЕНА

Answer (score 0):

> Цитата``"По Фасмеру происходит от др.-русск. супругъ «парная упряжка;" Следует из сказанного - супружеская пара. Предполагаю, что слово "супруги" может использоваться только во множественном числе при представлении пары.Своя или чья либо - "жена", но никак не супруга.